# Use of \numlist in macro

Tags: siunitx

I am writing exam questions. Some of these questions should be answered on graph paper, so I wrote a macro to (a) save time by avoiding re-typing the same instructions numerous times, and (b) ensure the instructions were given using consistent wording. After updating my LaTeX installation a few months ago, I now find that this macro no longer functions as expected. Can anyone help please? I suspect that `siunitx` may be (at least partly) to blame, but I really don't know where to start with this.

ETA: The expected output is `Answer parts (i), (ii) and (iii) of this question on the graph paper provided.`

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{etextools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\usegraphpaper}[1]{
    \textbf{Answer part\IfSubStr{#1}{;}{s}{} (\expandnext{\numlist[list-separator = {), (},list-final-separator = {) and (},list-pair-separator = {) and (},parse-numbers = false]}{\text{#1}}) of this question on the graph paper provided.} % Erroneous output

    \expandnext{\numlist[parse-numbers = false]}{#1} % Included to show what should appear between the parentheses
}

\begin{document}
    \usegraphpaper{i;ii;iii}

    \usegraphpaper{1;2;3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\expandnext` will do nothing at all to `\numlist`, which doesn't work by expansion.

I tried the code on TeX Live from 2012 to the current one and never got the output you'd like.

Here's a working version. Remember that `etextools` has always been unkind to other packages and the LaTeX kernel, so its usage is discouraged.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\usegraphpaper}{m}
  {
    \justint_graphpaper_prologue:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__justint_graphpaper_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__justint_graphpaper_items_paren_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \justint_graphpaper_prologue:n
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__justint_graphpaper_items_seq { ; } { #1 }
    \textbf
      {
       Answer~part
       \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__justint_graphpaper_items_seq > 1 } { s }
       \  % space
       \seq_set_map:NNn
         \l__justint_graphpaper_items_paren_seq % new seq
         \l__justint_graphpaper_items_seq % old seq
         { (##1) } % parenthesize items
       \seq_use:Nnnn \l__justint_graphpaper_items_paren_seq
         {~and~} % between two
         {,~} % between more than two
         {~and~} % between last two
       \  % space
       of~this~question~on~the~graph~paper~provided.
     }
  } % Erroneous output

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\usegraphpaper{i;ii;iii}

\usegraphpaper{1;2;3}

\usegraphpaper{4;5}

\usegraphpaper{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thankyou!

One further issue - I need the macro to output a (slightly) different message if an empty argument is passed. How do I achieve this?